# Step by step mathematical operations process

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, frontend, svg-animate

Not a hardcore coder, pardon me for the dumb question! If this is not the right platform to ask this question, please guide me to the right one.

I want to build a website that can show basic mathematical operations like division, multiplication, addition in a step-by-step process.

E.g.;
For division, I want to write a script (in JS), which can take a dividend (say 903) and a divisor (say 3) and produce the following steps.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Please share the approach or any framework to achieve the desired task. Someone told me to use SVG but I'm not sure how to handle infinitely many calculations. So, wanted to know about your views.

Comment: While it's an interesting question, it's still really broad imo and would require more time to answer than you may find many willing to volunteer. Sorry.

Comment: You dont need SVG (you can do it with SVG though). The layout can be done with HTML and CSS (with css grid layout or using flex). But the real challenge is to find where to place the letters and down arrows.

Comment: I also think it's too broad. Are you asking about the presentation or algorithms that produce the steps or both?

Comment: @Vasya
Right now, I'm searching for an algorithm or any framework which can do it. Even an appropriate resource to read would be a great help.